# Add a search box to stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, stackexchange.com

It would be mighty nifty to have search box that uses [google custom search](http://www.google.com/cse/) on the stackexchange.com site to search all the stack exchange sites.

This would both help drive traffic to the Stack Exchange site and help us find stuff that lives on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

[image: mockup]

Comment: I wish I had Photoshop skills like that. Also, freehand skill like that.

Comment: With all the up-and-coming Beta sites, I think this feature will be critical.  Otherwise we'll be seeing a lot more dupes, because people aren't going to search ten different sites before posting their question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now live.  Please try it out and see how you like it.

Currently we're showing ads while we evaluate it.  If people are getting a lot of use out of it, we can pay for the enterprise version to remove the ads.

implemented at http://stackexchange.com

[image]