# A common search box where it pull results from Stack Exchange network sites? What do you say?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a search box to stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66715/add-a-search-box-to-stackexchange-com)

A common search box where it pull results from Stack Exchange network sites? What do you say?

Won't it be great for Stack lovers...

Answer (score 4):

It already exsists: go to https://stackexchange.com/ and use the search box in the header.

Comment: Oh yes... right....